lookup() Method of javax.annotation.Resource not found when using JDK 11
Here is the sample code
@Resource(lookup = "java:....")
private Group group;
error:
error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method lookup()
[ERROR]   location: @interface Resource
In my pom.xml I added javax.annotation-api dependency but no luck
this was working fine while compiling in java1.8, when I am trying to compile in java 11 getting error.
How to resolve this?
